# Git quick repository setup

Tags: git, repository

I am a newbie with git. I have a linux server where i store code and host my website. 1 more guy works with me. We work from windows machine using cygwin. I am wondering, how to quickly set-up a git repo on server and then  be able to push and pull from our computers. This is what i did:

On Linux server: in the folder /home/user1/  I did

```
     1. "git init"    (this created a .git folder in the current folder)
     2. created "HelloGit.c" file and commited it to the repo
```

Now on Windows machine using cygwin, I am tryin to pull this repo by trying these, none of which work

1. "git clone user1@hostname:/home/user1/.git"      (This doesn't work)
              Then
2. I tried to create a bare repo and pull on this, so "git init --bare" and "git clone user1@hostname:/home/user1/.git" and still it doesn't work .

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Then I also tried: 
         git init --bare to create the repo
and git clone ssh://user1@hostname:/home/user1/ to clone

Comment: Try `git init --bare` and `git clone ssh://user1@hostname/home/user1.git`.

Comment: tried that as well. Doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The two commands on server

```
cd /home/user1; git init --bare
```

and on client

```
git clone ssh://user1@server/home/user1
```

should work. If it doesn't, try running with `--verbose` to see what's wrong. Setting `GIT_TRACE=1` before running the git command might reveal additional information.

One problem might be a missing `sshd`. Another problem could be permission problems on your repository. Try logging into the server and clone the repository there

```
client> ssh server
server> cd /tmp
server> git clone /home/user1
```

Your second try  `git init --bare` and `git clone ssh://user1@hostname:/home/user1` is wrong though, because of the second `:`. Try `git clone ssh://user1@hostname/home/user1` instead.

Comment: I think the problem is missing sshd. Because i tried sshd command on command line and it failed. I am using cygwin and trying to figure out how to install sshd. thanks a lot, I would update here and accept the answer as soon as i can confirm this.

Comment: @user743914 Don't start sshd on the command line, try `ps aux | grep sshd` on the server instead. You can also do `ssh server` on the client. You get a `connection refused`, when the sshd is not running.

Comment: thanks, but I am able to ssh/scp to the server. I tried the --verbose option which also didn't bring anything back. Is there a place where git might be writing all the actions. Like a log file in application servers like tomcat ? Also, interesting thing is,it doesn't even ask me for the password when i am trying to close, while in normal ssh, it asks me for password immediately.

Comment: @user743914 You can set `GIT_TRACE=1`. This might show additional information. What error messages do you get? Try also cloning on the server.

Comment: Cloning on the server locally works as given in your comment.             This is the output on setting GIT_TRACE=1 : trace: built-in: git 'clone' '--verbose' 'ssh://user1@host/myrepo.git'
trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'user1@host' 'git-upload-pack '\''/myrepo.git                                                                                                                '\'''
Cloning into 'myrepo'...

Comment: @user743914 This looks like my tests. And then it must ask for the ssh password.

Comment: Afterwards, I realized that i am running git 1.8 on windows and 1.7.1 on linux machine. So, i have now changed to 1.7.11 on both the machines. Still the same problem. However on windows it says : "git version 1.7.11.msysgit.1". What's msysgit ?

Comment: [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) is a collection of tools built and intended to be used with MinGW.